# Pipes not working as expected on Mac

Tags: c, macos, pipe

I have two `C` programs named `sender` and `getter`.
`sender` prints two strings, `"Hello\n"` and `"it works\n"` on the `stdout`.
And the `getter` reads strings from the `stdin` and prints the read data on the `stdout`.

Both `sender` and `getter` are **NOT** meant to be worked together. However, I tried to connect the `stdout` of `sender` to `stdin` of `getter` using `pipe` on my MacBook Pro.

### sender.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fputs("Hello\n", stdout);
    fputs("it works\n", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

### getter.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char msg[80];
    while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\0]s", msg) != -1) // Keep reading unless the length of string is -1
        fprintf(stdout, "--> %s\n", msg);   /* Point worth noting. 
                                               Every string read from stdin is prepended with 
                                               a "-->" to indicate that it's the getter program 
                                               printing the string and not the sender program.
                                             */

    fflush(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected output:

```
--> Hello
--> it works
```

### Actual output:

```
--> Hello
it works // You can see that "-->" is missing here. Which clearly means that it's the sender program printing this on the terminal and not the getter.
```

- Why is this happening? Why is my `getter` program not reading `"it works\n"` from `sender`?
- Why is my `sender` program printing `"it works\n"` on the terminal window if it's `stdout` is connected to `stdin` of getter?
- How am I supposed to get the expected output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Which clearly means that it's the sender program printing this on the terminal" - no, it doesn't mean that. It means your first `fscanf()` in `getter.c` call grabbed the entire input in one go, both lines at once. If you want to read one line at a time, you have to write your program to do that, for instance using `fgets()`. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Hey is it? How can I then test if what you are saying is right? please let me know. shall I reduce the size of array from `80` to `5` or something?

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` to read one line at a time. You can test it by having `getter.c` write its input to a file instead of to `stdout`, since you know `sender.c` is not writing to that file, or by having `getter.c` also output the number of characters it just wrote.

Comment: Your format string for `fscanf()` in `getter` is broken; the embedded `\0` terminates the scan set before the close square bracket (the format string ends at the first null byte!).  Additionally, the sender is not writing null bytes to the pipe.

Comment: But how do I determine the number of lines printed by `sender.c` if I use `fgets()`? Coz `fgets()` returns a `char *`. With `fscanf()`, I can compare it with `-1` in the `while` loop.

Comment: `fgets()` returns `NULL` on failure, so check for that. You can determine the number of lines printed by counting the number of `-->`s that are output as per your original plan.

Comment: I did not compare `fgets()` with anything but did this: `while(fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin)){/*code*/}`. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: @Aditya: That *is* comparing `fgets()` with `NULL`, it's just doing so implicitly. It's a perfectly fine way of performing the check.

Comment: @paul thanks for the help. I know it implicitly compares ot with NULL. And terminates once NULL is returned. I was too stupid with this question. Thanks.

Comment: fscanf does not return a -1 unless that was a major problem.  Normally it returns the number of successful input/conversions,  in the case, it should return 1.  also, there is no '\0' being output by the sender.  As others have stated, use fgets().  Suggest reading the manual for each function you use.

Comment: What are you trying to say, sir?

Comment: @user3629249: `fscanf()` returns `EOF` on end-on-input, which is a normal condition and hardly a "major problem". Writing `EOF` instead of `-1` would be better.

Comment: How different is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets()` reads till newline character `\n` and also includes it into the buffer to which the line was read. So in your case sender has put a newline at the end of each line

So do

```
while(fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin) != NULL)
```

Make sure that your strings are NULL terminated. If you want to count the number of lines successfully read than have a `count` within the while loop incremented .

Comment: Oh yes. This worked. I thought of using `fgets()`. But couldn't think of it to compare it with `NULL`. As I had this thing of comparing `-1` with `fscanf()`. So what could have I compared `fgets()` with? Lol. Me stupid. Thanks.! :)